# Pop up while re-subscribing for product in sandbox environment

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I am creating app in which user have to subscribe for product for 1 month/year. I was testing app in sandbox environment. For that i created test user account from itunes connect. I purchase product first time everything went ok. After 2-3 minutes I re-subscribe  for same product I get alert with message "You’ve already purchased this in-app purchase but it hasn’t been downloaded". I try purchasing with different test account but got same message.

I want to ask weather this popup will reject my app from app store?

Answer (score 0):

It pop's up if you try to buy a subscription while it's still active.

The user doesn't have to pay for that,so that's ok.

But you'd better not show that button,that allows user to buy a purchase,if he has already bought it)

Comment: @Nikita..can i use yhis with ownserver nil

Comment: What do you mean by that?Use this with your own server?What exactly you want to use?

Comment: I was not using server for verification of the reciept.because i was providing a set of contents to the user from cloud if he was taken that subscription.inorder to get to that page the user needs a subscription.so i am using ownserver as nil.is there any pbm for that....i was taking the expiry date from the reciept and checking it with todays date..thats all